# FTP: 450 Can't Access File

Tags: ftp

First of all this may belong on SU so feel free to migrate. Problem is as follows

Getting this error when trying to upload a specific file to a specific directory on a Windows-based FTP server (Filezilla to be accurate)

The error is as follows:

> 450 can't access file

I can upload this particular file to any other directory on the server. If I rename the file to something else (I was originally overwriting a file) the same problem persists. A file of the given name is written to the directory but it's size is 0 bytes.

I've tried the Filezilla FTP client and the MS command line client.

Rebooting the server isn't an option right now and I can't connect to the machine remotely (thats another issue, another question). I will be able to reboot the machine tomorrow - just focusing on this error at the moment.

Has this happened to anyone before? Is there a way of resolving it given my situation?

Edit: Just wanted to clarify that I have full permissions on the server, including this directory

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked within Filezilla that you have full (Read/write/Delete and Modify) access within the shared folder that you setup with Filezilla. 
This is different from the file access rights on the server